# Saving information from being compromised by url change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In some webpages or views, I have information displayed in table. Column values are rendered as links.

Problems:

1. When I hover over the link, it's URL is visible at the bottom of browser.
2. When I click on link, I show information for the resource requested in URL. (www.someurl.com/Employee/67 gives me information of employee with id = 67).

   Now, this URL is displayed in browser. If you change URL to www.someurl.com/Employee/88, it shows information of employee with id = 88 though the logged in user is not supposed to see information for employee id 88

This are serious security breaches.

I am thinking of following as possible solutions:

URL masking at application level

Base64 encoding of URL to shorten and obfuscate it, so that users can't just throw values in the URL.

`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenValidation` mechanism

Is there better and more secure approach other than above to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check in Controller serving www.someurl.com/Employee/88 if currently authenticated user has access to Employee with ID 88 and throw exception if he does not - no need to mask url.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is not supposed to be able to see the employee with the id of 88 then they should not be able to see the information for the employee with id 88. The URL is more or less irrelevant and is in your case only giving them an obvious clue as to how to gain unauthorised access to data in your system.

You need a proper security plan where data is only served from the database to the UI via the business layer if the logged in user if authorised to see that data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea about your first approach security breach:

Mix your id with some GUID or complex structure while sending it, and when you receive it, took out your id from this and then proceed. [ Your masking idea]